# IIS 7.5 Windows Authentication not working on Chrome - Error 401.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, authentication, iis

Have an issue with getting Windows Authentication to work on Google Chrome on a Win 2012 Web Server. IE works fine.

- The application is calling the server and returning a 401.2 Unauthorised error message.
- It is also returning a response header of 'WWW-Authenticate:NLTM'
- Opening the request URL in a new tab returns status 200 and the 'Persistent-Auth: true' header.

I have tried many things over the last day:

1. Windows Auth Extended protection and kernel-mode auth are disabled.
2. Moved 'NTLM' provider above 'Negotiate'.
3. Remove 'Negotiate' providers all together.
4. The site is in the intranet zone and has permissions to automatically login with the user's credentials.

Comment: What's in the request headers when you try accessing it via Chrome? Are you wanting to use basic-authentication?

Comment: @sytech I am using Windows Authentication as it is an intranet site. The web application is not sending any custom headers.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your configuration files? Particularly the `<authentication>` section. Keep in mind this is configurable both at the site and application level.

Comment: @sytech the web.config does not have an <authentication> section as i have configured in ISS. Windows Auth is enabled, all other types are disabled; Windows Auth providers are NTLM, Negotiate. This is at server and application level.

Comment: Is there a reason why you disabled kernel mode? Does your app pool use a custom identity? The HTTP error 401.2 means *"Logon Failed Due to Server Configuration with No Authentication"*  Also, MS documentation says *"If you need to support clients other than those running Internet Explorer, you may want to enable Basic authentication in conjunction with NTLM or Kerberos"* Have you tried enabling basic authentication?